# Getting data from my ERP System to my Power BI data model

Tags: sql, excel, database, powerbi, erp

I am trying to find the optimal way of getting data from three different sources to a single Power BI model.
The sources being used vary in style:

1. Manually updated Excel spreadsheets
2. Excel spreadsheet with built in queries (server holding ERP system data)
3. Excel spreadsheet being written to by another application
   The priority datasets are the first two.
   I have little experience in this area so I do not know if the way that it is currently set up is ideal. I am also worried that as this model is scaled to include more and more sources, that issues will arise.

Currently all sources and the Power BI file are on a SharePoint. The Power BI model uses the "Web" data source to link to the files in the SharePoint.
Limitations of this are that to refresh the query in the spreadsheet mentioned in point 2, the file needs to be opened in the desktop app from the SharePoint.
More importantly and as stated above, I feel as more and more sources are added to this model that issues could arise.
Is there a standard way of dealing with growing data models like this? Is this what software packages like Azure are designed for? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My issue is not related to any code being used in this project. It is related to the systems being used. Thanks.